# Front, driver-side wheel sounds like it's skidding when braking

Tags: tires, brakes, wheels

I have a Nissan Micra (UK, 51-plate, 2001 model) and I've today noticed a sound a bit like skidding when I apply the brakes, gently, around 30mph. Driving and steering as usual is fine, no unusual pull to the left or right. It's due for it's service in a few weeks so I can get it looked at then - if I know what to ask the mechanic to look for. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your tires fully inflated?

Comment: @BobCross, yes. Solid, but with some give.

Comment: Let me rephrase: have you checked your tire pressures with a gauge?  Do they match the recommended pressures for your car?  There's a plate inside the drivers side door (in the US) that lists the correct pressures.  They're also found in the owner's manual.

Comment: Tyre pressures were checked and all okay. I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the car was due for it's MOT and service I took it into the garage who diagnosed worn front brake pads and reccomended replacement. Since the replacement of the pads I have not had any further issues.

Comment: Great - congrats for getting it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Modern radial tires can look/feel just fine from the outside while still being dangerously low on air pressure.  Skidding type sounds are typical for a tire with low air pressure.